# MATLAB what lines are different between matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to find the number of the lines where the values of two matrices are not the same

I found only a way to know the indexs on the not same items by:

```
find(a~=b)
```

where a is `N*N` and b is `N*N`

How can I know the rows numbers of the not same items

ps

looking for nicer way then

dint the find and then having some vector in a loop filling with

```
ind2sub(size(A), 6)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`max`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) on the logical array of such matches or mis-mistaches in this case along  a certain dimension, alongwith `find`.

If you are looking to find unique row IDs for mismatches, do this -

```
find(max(a~=b,[],2))
```

For unique column IDs, just change the dimension specifier -

```
find(max(a~=b,[],1))
```

Sample run -

```
>> a
a =
     1     2     2     2     1
     1     2     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     2     1     1
>> b
b =
     1     2     1     1     2
     1     2     1     2     1
     2     2     2     2     1
     1     1     2     2     2
>> a~=b
ans =
     0     0     1     1     1
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     1
>> find(max(a~=b,[],2)) %// unique row IDs
ans =
     1
     2
     4
>> find(max(a~=b,[],1)) %// unique col IDs
ans =
     3     4     5
```

Comment: working great, looking for help to understand the max but i didnt get it,, any chance u can tell us how max works, what the inputs means?

Comment: @JohnnyF With `max(A,[],1)`, we are trying to find the maximum value along `dim=1` and similarly to find along `dim=2`, we do `max(A,[],2)`. That `[]` tells us that the next input argument would specifiy the dimension. Instead, if you do `max(A,1)`, it would give you elementwise `max` between elements of `A` and scalar `1`. In our case, we are looking to operate on just one input, so `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

here I found an easy way if any one will need it

```
indexs=find(a~=b)
[~,rows]=ind2sub(size(a),indexs)
rows=unique( sort( rows ) )
```

now rows are only the different rows

Comment: `unique` has the sorting build in: `rows = unique(rows, 'descending')`. I also think you can directly use `[rows,~] = find(a~=b)`, which should be faster.

Comment: These would give you unique column IDs, right? Are you looking to get unique row IDs or column IDs?

Answer (score 1):

```
NotSame = 0;
for ii = 1:size(a,1)
    if a(ii,:) ~= b(ii,:)
       NotSame = NotSame+1;
    end
end
```

This checks it row by row and when a row in `a` is not the same as the row in `b` this will increase the count of `NotSame`. Not the fastest way, I'm sure someone can produce a solution using `bsxfun`, but I'm not an expert in that.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the double output of find

```
[row, col] = find(a~=b)
myrows = unique(row);
```

You can also have the columns where a & b have different values

```
mycols = unique(col);
```